# Image on React and/or CSS not appearing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, background-image

I am unable to insert an image to my sign up page. I have tried inserting it using index.js (HTML codes in React component) and also in the corresponding CSS file. Both not working. Sharing the codes and screenshot below (I have removed irrelevant import codes):

React Component code:

```
import styles from "./register.css";

    return(
        <div>
            <div id="styledImg">
                <img alt="" title="" src="../../src/assets/bocLogo.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

CSS code:

```
#styledImg {
    width: 1110px;
    height: 428px;
    height: 428px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 245px;
    left: 87px;
}

#styledImg Img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try importing the image: `import theimage from "src/blah/blah/theimage.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the image and then use the imported file as `src`.
it would be something like this.

```
import logo from '.../../src/assets/bocLogo.png';
```

and then you will use this logo in `src`

```
<img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
```

for more information please check [This link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload that image as a ReactComponent.
`import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../../assets/your-image.png";`
So that should look like:

```
import styles from "./register.css";
import { ReactComponent as Image } from "../../assets/your-image.png"

    return(
        <div>
            <div id="styledImg">
                <img alt="" title="" src={Image}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing!

What's the difference with simply importing it as 'logo' for example, and not as a React Component? Which one is better?

Comment: Well if you import it as a React Component, you will be able to use this image as a React Component ->   <Image />. Whereas with just logo, you will have to write down <img ...> tag. This example actually shows a bad example, because React Component is being used on <img ... /> tag. But you get the point